# How display the HTML response in a Python script from an another script?

Tags: python, html, cgi

I have recently learn Python and programming.
I m trying to write a cgi script for upload a file to an another script that compute the md5 hash and store it in sqlite database.

this is the first script for sending the file and an area text :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8
import cgi,cgitb,time

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
print '''
<html><head>
  <title>Files storage</title>

    </head><body style="
    background-color: f4f4f4;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    ">
    <div id="container" style="
    border: 1px solid rgb(0,100,200);
    padding: 5px 20px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    ">
    <p><b>Select the file to upload :</b></p>
    <form method="post" action="arch0_1.py" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>File: <input type="file" name="up_file"><br><p>
    <label for="description">File description (max. 255 characters) :</label><br>
    <textarea name="tag" id="description" style="margin: 2px; width: 389px; height: 108px;"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    </div>
    </body></html>
'''
```

On the other script, i treat the data, and finish my script with:

```
if fileitem.filename:
  fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
  open ('/archivages/tmp_file/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())

  message = 'The file "' + fn +'" was uploaded successfully'
else:
  message = 'No files was uploaded'

print """\
    Content-Type: text/html\n
    <html>
    <body>
       <p>%s</p>
       </body>
       </html>
       """ % (message,)
```

How is the better way to get the last "print" in the first script to display the text in the web browser?

Answer (score -1):

we can write a jquery post to catch the response text from the result.

Comment: I find the solution, my header was wrong !

    print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
    print """
       <html>
       <body>
         <p>%s</p>
         </body>
         </html>
         """ % (message,)